# Componente dialog atualizar

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Possuo o seguinte `dialog`:

```
<p:dialog header="#{encomendaController.objeto.id == null ? msg['cadastrando'] : msg['atualizando']} Encomenda" widgetVar="cadastroEdicao"
        minHeight="80" id="dialog">
        <h:panelGrid id="cadastro" columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel value="Código" for="codigo" />
            <p:inputText id="codigo" value="#{encomendaController.objeto.codigo}" required="true" />
            <p:message for="codigo" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Descrição" for="descricao" />
            <p:inputText id="descricao" value="#{encomendaController.objeto.descricao}" />
            <p:message for="descricao" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Loja/Origem" for="loja" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="loja" value="#{encomendaController.objeto.loja}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{enumHelper.obterLojas()}" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean}" itemValue="#{bean}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="loja" />
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{encomendaController.salvar}"
                update="cadastro,:listaEncomendas:messages,:listaEncomendas:viewFull:resultadoPendentes" oncomplete="PF('cadastroEdicao').hide();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
```

Até aí tudo bem, pois se trata de um form para cadastro ou edição de um registro. Eu também possuo um `dataTable` onde possuo um botão para editar aquele registro x. O que eu preciso é que ao acionar o botão de editar, seja aberto o dialog e os registros carregados, isso também está funcionando. O que acontece é que o título deveria aparecer Atualizando e não Cadastrando como ocorre em um cadastro novo. Na minha condição do header eu referenciei o `objeto == null`. O meu método de editar é simples :

```
public void editar(Long id) throws Exception {
        setObjeto(service.find(id));
    }


<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{encomendaController.editar(bean.id)}"
                    update=":listaEncomendas:viewFull:cadastroEdicaoForm:cadastro,resultadoPendentes" process="@this" onclick="PF('cadastroEdicao').show();" />
```

Eu coloquei o id do dialog no update do botão mas meio que bagunça a tela toda, alguém pode ajudar ?

Answer (score 0):

faça um teste, substitua o `==` por `eq`.

> Eu coloquei o id do dialog no update do botão mas meio que bagunça a tela toda, alguém pode ajudar ?

O que normalmente se faz é adicionar um `h:form` dentro do dialog, e na chamado do `dialog.show()` aplicar um update para o id do form, e não do dialog em si. Outra coisa, sem o form não vai rolar o submit do seu botão salvar.